# Include a file inside Visual project in order to use it

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, file, import, include

I would like to include a file name "7zip.exe" inside a visual project in order to use it in my code.

My code:
I scan a folder, for each file use "7zip.exe" to extact data. I don't use(zlib & libzip too painfull on windows).

I think I find an ugly way, put a hexa dump of "7zip.exe" , puts it into a header (tmp.h) and after to write a file with the dump.

If you add a better idea,..
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, maybe you are looking for the function CreateProcess from kernel32.dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed a EXE in a resource, extract and execute it.  Keep in mind that an EXE may have dependent DLLs.

[Embedding an external executable inside a C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798655/embedding-an-external-executable-inside-a-c-sharp-program)

However, I would suggest you look at the [7Zip DLL](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) instead (also available from 7-zip.org).