# How to manually create an installer in visual c#

Tags: c#, installation

I have 2 programs that needs to install before users can use my program, I want to create one program that will run both of these in order. I know this can be a batch script but i want the installer to have a gui where it should set some initial settings, like install paths and such. creating the program i can do, i just don't know how to add the two programs to my installer. in the end i just want to distribute the one installer not three installers.

How do i add the two executables to my installer program?

Comment: Just keep in mind: If you write your own installer complete from scratch it still only does work when the .NET-Framework is installed already.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have liked NSIS.  There's already lots of examples of how to install .NET and then your own program or programs in one install.  It has its own scripting language, so is not written in C#, but as someone who has used other MSI based approaches, NSIS is alot simpler.  MSI is a huge pain(but I think some things like WIX make is simpler, but there's alot of gotchas with MSI).

You could even have NSIS run a C# app that does some additional installation steps after .NET and the app itself is installed(or maybe just extract the C# finishing installer to a temp directory.)

You can include executables as resources in a C# app and then write them out, but it will be alot simpler and probably faster to just let NSIS package them and extract them for you, then you can do whatever you need to do with them in your finishing C# installer.

Writing from scratch you will find yourself probably doing alot of things that NSIS already covers, in addition to trying to solve the .NET dependency problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WiX ToolSet](http://wixtoolset.org/). It has a lot of samples.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand... you already have your C# installer program ready and running (no MSI or other installer technologies), now you need to add those additional exe programs to that installer right?

If that's the case, you need to embed those programs as embedded resources, then you can extract them and execute in the desired order before install your main program.

There's some information about how to use binary embedded resources here:

[Embedding an external executable inside a C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798655/embedding-an-external-executable-inside-a-c-sharp-program)

http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~vs667/articles/embed_executable_tutorial/