# Can you put a Unity 3d game in a Xamarin cross platform app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, xamarin, cross-platform

Can you put a Unity 3d game in a Xamarin cross platform app?

I am developing a Game using Unity 3D, and I would like to include the game in my Xamarin Cross Platform App.

The Game is a mini game that I will give away free to customers who download and use my App.

Is this possible?

Comment: Unity3D is already cross-platform

Comment: @Roy Did you read the question?   I want to know if I can place my Unity 3d game in an existing Xamarin App?   I dont want two seperate apps I want one app that has content for my users and also has a Bonus Section with the mini game, all in the same app, not two apps.

Comment: i dont think so that this is possible

Comment: Ugghhhh, are you serious??   @CDrosos can you offer any other ideas for what I want to accomplish?  I have already built a rather large sized app in Xamarin and published it in the App Store, Search: Merricks Jewelry, and want to add an additional mini game to it...  Any ideas????

Comment: check this out http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-add-ins-for-monodevelop-xamarin-studio-5-9.329880/

Comment: Great answer @CDrosos !!!  I like that article, Not sure how reliable there plugin is however, but seems pretty legit.  Thanks!

Comment: nice to hear that,if this plugin is good tell me and i will put it as an answer to better help othes too.

Answer (score 6):

> Can you put a Unity 3d game in a Xamarin cross platform app?

It depends.

Assuming you are not talking about browser games, Unity creates its own executable and/or entry point.  You would probably have to take the Unity3D-created game and embed that as a resource in the original app, say a Windows Phone app.  Then launch the game as a child process.

The original app:

[image: The original app]

You may be able to embed a Unity3D-created Windows phone app as a resource in an existing Windows Phone application.  You could just spawn it as a child process?

[image: The embedded Unity3D game]

### Web Game

However, there is nothing stopping you from making a game in Unity3D and having it generate a *web game*.

> *Access complimentary build options for Web publishing in Unity 5. Once a user installs it, the hugely popular Unity Web Player plugin updates automatically. Use it to deploy to Internet Explorer, Safari, Mozilla Firefox and more.* [Tell me more](https://unity3d.com/unity/multiplatform)

Your Xamaring app can then simply display a web browser from which you can play your game.

[image]

### Browser Shell Apps

I see your *"Merricks Jewelry"* app is already on the iOS store. Be warned that should you pursue the web game approach, I know at one point Apple were strict at one point about native apps that were essentially shells for web-based content.  You may need to check with Apple.  It may still be the case or it may not.

Comment: Very nice @Micky  thank you very much for your in depth comment.  I am thinking now that I will just publish the game stand alone, undedr Merricks Jewelry Monster Explorer, the game is so big that I will just publish it by itself.  The options you layed out seem reasonable and straight forward enough, so I can look at them in the future if I need.  You wouldnt happen to have a link to a tutorial on embedding Unity 3d games as app resources would you?  Anyways, thanks again!

Comment: @MattyMerrix Thank-you good sir.  [Here's one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798655/embedding-an-external-executable-inside-a-c-sharp-program).  It's for WinForms but the concept is the same.