# Add Unity project to Xamarin project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, xamarin

I'm working on a Xamarin Project in which I'd like to integrate an augmented reality app I've made with Unity (as an external resource).
Does anyone know if that's possible or not? And how can I do that?

Comment: you can read more at http://answers.unity3d.com/topics/xamarin.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33042514/can-you-put-a-unity-3d-game-in-a-xamarin-cross-platform-app