# Open Unity3D game in Xamarin Form / Xamarin App in Unity3D

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, xamarin, augmented-reality

I'm trying to integrate Unity3D game into Xamarin Forms.

- If it is possible how to manage the Unity assets in Xamarin...?
- Is it possible unity game/xamarin app as a library and open in Xamarin/Unity...?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33042514/can-you-put-a-unity-3d-game-in-a-xamarin-cross-platform-app) answer helps you.

If your game it's a web game it's very easy just use a [webview](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/), but I assume is not the case.

In my opinion you should do a build per OS, it's very easy with unity editor, you will save time and useless problems.

Hope I helped you.