# How do I distribute Python with a .Net application as one installation executable?

Tags: python, c#, .net

I have a .NET application written in C#, on Visual Studio, that calls some Python scripts to run data through some Machine Learning scripts, models and processes.

I have a requirement to distribute the software as a single installation package/executable onto Windows platform machines that may not have either python nor .NET runtime libraries installed.

Distribution of either a .NET application or a Python application (to include the Python runtimes) appears to be well documented, but how do I marry the two?

Note: It does not matter whether the final installation executable is produced by Python or .NET (Visual Studio) only that it is distributed as one installation package/executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have experience with C#, but you could try to compile the python script using
[pyinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/), which compiles python code to a stand-alone executable.

Then, you can try embedding this executable into your C# program, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798655/embedding-an-external-executable-inside-a-c-sharp-program).